# JSON.stringify produces junk characters

Tags: node.js, json

I have a object which holds some user information like username, encrypted password and role.

I need to send this to RocketChat API using WebSocket.

Once the object is created I use JSON.stringify(usr_obj) and send it.

Suprisingly; though it works on almost all instances, somehow it is failing on 2 instances.

It produces something like `":{"0":"{","1":"\"","2":"u","3":"s","4":"e","5"}}`

There is no change in the configuration (but the one which is failing is on Ubuntu 18.04 and the one working well is on Ubuntu 16.04) Is there a connection?

Comment: Can you print JSON.parse(usr_obj) once before JSON.stringify in your question?

Comment: How is encrypted password stored in the object field? If its format is binary, a conversion to a printable string (e.g. base64) before stringifying might help (just an hypothesis)